# Deezer JS SDK does not recognize redirect uri

Tags: deezer

I am developing an app for Deezer.

I have init like this

```
<div id="dz-root"></div>
<script>
        window.dzAsyncInit = function () {
            DZ.init({
                appId: 'xxxxxx',
                channelUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/channel'
            });
        };
        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = '//e-cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('dz-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
</script>
```

The uri `http://localhost:9000/channel` only has a script tag with source to the Deezer JS SDK.

On developer console, I have

- App Domain: `localhost:9000`
- Redirect Uri: `http://localhost:9000/channel`

I am still being greeted with "you must enter a valid redirect uri". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It happens when the "Application domain" filled in the application form on http://developers.deezer.com/myapps/app/xxxxx/edit is not the same that the "redirect_uri" value where you want to redirect.

Comment: Are you saying that "App Domain" should be exactly the same as "Redirect Uri"? I actually found the same answer on StackOverflow and I still find that very cryptic. Should I change my "Redirect Uri" to `http://localhost:9000` then? The uri wants the "http" part.

Comment: Your app domain should only be localhost:9000